# Using Android Data Binding with many-to-many relationship in model

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm new to Android development and have been experimenting with two-way data binding. While I've been able to perform some basic bindings between the view and the model, I've come across a scenario where I need to update a many-to-many relationship between two entities.

Consider the following (contrived) example:

```java
public class Person extends BaseObservable {

    private Set<Thing> things;

    @Bindable
    public boolean hasThing(Thing thing) {
        return things.contains(thing);
    }

    public void setHasThing(Thing thing, boolean hasThing) {
        boolean changed = hasThing
                ? things.add(thing)
                : things.remove(thing);

        if (changed) {
            // notify change
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to bind an `onChecked` event with the action of adding or removing a `Thing` from a `Person`:

```xml
<data>
    <variable name="person" type="org.example.model.Person"/>
    <variable name="thing" type="org.example.model.Thing"/>
</data>

<!-- obviously doesn't work -->
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:checked="@={person.hasThing(thing)}"/>
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this? I've looked into `@BindingMethod` and `@BindingAdapter`, but:

- According to the Javadoc, `@BindingMethod` has constraints around the parameters and return types of the methods which seem to make it more suitable for use cases such as type conversions
- `@BindingAdapter`/`@InverseBindingAdapter` seems promising, but I'm struggling to wrap my head around how to trigger the adapter:

  ```xml
  <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
          android:checked="@={?}"
          app:person="@{person}"
          app:thing="@{thing}"/>
  ```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was making this more difficult than it needs to be.

The following works:

```xml
<data>
    <variable name="person" type="org.example.model.Person"/>
    <variable name="thing" type="org.example.model.Thing"/>
</data>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:checked="@{person.hasThing(thing)}"
        app:onCheckedChanged="@{(view, checked) -> person.setHasThing(thing, checked)}"/>
```

```java
@BindingAdapter("onCheckedChanged")
public static void setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton button, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener changeListener) {
    button.setOnCheckedChangeListener(changeListener);
}
```